# Publish only certain artifacts from one big project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, azure-devops, repository, pom.xml

I have set up maven repository in azure-devops where I can publish artifacts. I want to publish only certain artifacts from my big project which I am not able to achieve

I am using this xml snippet in pom.xml to publish packages

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>msazure-visualstudio-com-msazure-sampleid</id>
        <url>https://msazure.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/sampleid/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>msazure-visualstudio-com-msazure-sampleid</id>
        <url>https://msazure.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/sampleid/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

for example:

I have parent project P and first level child projects c1, c2, c3

c2 and c3 have dependency on c1
Only c2 and c1 needs to be published, not c3

When I try to consume c1 artifact in c2, it requires parent artifact available as well, so I published P as well

but when I do that the changes propagate to all child projects and c3 also get published which I don't want

I can put c3 into separate project and publish everything in P: P, c1 and c2 but is there any other way to do it without separating projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set `<skip>true</skip>` in the maven deploy plugin in the project c3.

Comment: I am new to Maven. I don't see maven deploy plugin in any of my projects. So far we  never ran deploy, we were only running mvn install. Basically we always referenced files directly and from local repository and never published anything. Can you please give example of maven plugin that I have to put in P, c1 and c3?

Comment: What do you mean by "publish only certain artifacts" in your question? Don't you mean to call `mvn deploy`?

Comment: publish only certain artifacts: I mean to say that, I don't want to publish all the artifacts but only some artifacts which are used by others. Thats what I was trying to explaing in my example as well. And yes we have a cmd at root folder which will call mvn deploy

Comment: You need to add the maven deploy plugin configuration as described in https://mincong-h.github.io/2018/08/04/maven-deploy-artifacts-to-nexus/ Then you need to add the skip property to the modules you don't want to deploy.